# Azure explorer get an error when uploading files

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

When I tried to upload some files to cdn I get an alert message:

[image]

And no matter I choose Yes or no , I get an error. Would someone help me look at this? Thanks a lot

[image]

Comment: What kind of file are you uploading? And what is the tool you're using to upload the file?

Comment: css files and even I try to upload a 20kb css file It also not works

Comment: It looks like you're using Redgate's Azure Explorer. It seems there's an issue with the tool itself. May I suggest using other tool for uploading. Like Microsoft's Storage Explorer.

Comment: I use windows10 and to the same file I use my colleague's PC he can successfully upload. And we use the same latest version of Azure explorer

Comment: Thanks then I'll firstly try to use Microsoft's Storage Explorer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your screenshot, you are try to upload a file as **[pageblob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/understanding-block-blobs--append-blobs--and-page-blobs)**. Please have a try to upload it as block blob.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and I'm not sure how to use a blockblob . I just copy paste it to an existing folder on cdn. Does it has any option for the users to choose as upload as blockblob?

Comment: We could use [Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer](http://storageexplorer.com) to do that easily.